# как так вышло? что отвечает за подсчёт букв?

Tags: javascript

```js
function countChar(string, ch) {
  let counted = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (string[i] == ch) {
      counted += 1;
    }
  }
  return counted;
}

function countBs(string) {
  return countChar(string, "B");
}

console.log(countBs("BBC"));
// → 2
console.log(countChar("kakkerlak", "k"));
// → 4
```

Comment: буквы считаются в функции countChar, в чем заключается вопрос - непонятно

Comment: все сходится, что не так?

Comment: а в чем проблема то? функция считает количество указанного символа в слове. в слове "BBC" 2 буквы B, а в слове "kakkerlak" 4 буквы k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function countChar(string, ch) { //получаем в функцию строку и искомый символ
  let counted = 0; // объявляем счетчик и его начальное значение.
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) { //в цикле перебираем каждый символ строки
    if (string[i] == ch) { // сравниваем каждый символ строки с искомым
      counted += 1; // если if true, то увеличиваем счетчик на 1
    }
  }
  return counted; //функция возвращает счетчик, 
//то есть, итоговое количество символов в строке
} 

function countBs(string) {
  return countChar(string, "B");
}

console.log(countBs("BBC"));
// → 2
console.log(countChar("kakkerlak", "k"));
// → 4
```

Comment: спасибо за понятное объяснение